# Android RecyclerView "cannot find symbol variable"

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-databinding

My problem is that I am writing a program which contains 2 RecyclerViews in 2 different activities. The first one worked like a charm.  No troubles at all. The second one, on the other hand, is not working. It should be exactly the same situation, I'm doing exactly the same thing but I just can't get rid of the error.

[image]

For now, I'll just provide my Activity Class, My Adapter and my corresponding XML File.

The bold part in the following methods also spit out a "Cannot resolve symbol" and I guess it has to do with the problem above but when I try to run the app only the error above gets shown.

```
binding.listItem.**setAdapter**(adapter);
binding.listItem.**setLayoutManager**(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Adapter:

```
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<User> users;
private Context context;

public UserAdapter(List<User> users, Context context) {
    this.users = users;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public UserAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    SubmitListItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil
            .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()),
                    R.layout.submit_list_item,
                    viewGroup,
                    false);
    return new ViewHolder(binding);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    User user = users.get(i);
    viewHolder.submitListItemBinding.setUser(user);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return users.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public SubmitListItemBinding submitListItemBinding;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull SubmitListItemBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        submitListItemBinding = binding;
    }
}
}
```

Activity:

```
public class SubmitLayout extends AppCompatActivity {
private UserAdapter adapter;
private SubmitListItemBinding binding;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_submit_layout_);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String s = intent.getStringExtra("group");

    Group group = new Gson().fromJson(s, Group.class);
    List<User> users = group.getAllUsers();

    binding  = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.submit_list_item);
    adapter = new UserAdapter(users, this);

    binding.listItem.setAdapter(adapter);
    binding.listItem.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

}
}
```

XML Activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>
    <variable
        name="user"
        type="com.hasenbau.gemeinschaftskasse_android.model.User"/>
</data>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutSubmit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".SubmitLayout">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listItem"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

And finally the ListItem XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
    <variable
        name="user"
        type="com.hasenbau.gemeinschaftskasse_android.model.User"/>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/whoListItemTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:text="Marv"
        android:text="@{String.valueOf(user.name)}"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/Darkblue"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/howMuchListItemTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:text="bezahlen"
        android:text="bezahlen"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/Darkblue"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/whatForListItemTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:text="100€"
        android:text="@{String.valueOf(user.balance)}"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/Darkblue"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

### Update

After trying to invalidate cache I go this IDE Error :

```
java.lang.Throwable
at com.intellij.psi.impl.DebugUtil.startPsiModification(DebugUtil.java:512)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.DebugUtil.performPsiModification(DebugUtil.java:542)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.file.impl.FileManagerImpl.processFileTypesChanged(FileManagerImpl.java:268)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.file.impl.FileManagerImpl$1.exitDumbMode(FileManagerImpl.java:89)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBusConnectionImpl.java:117)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.doPumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:426)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpWaitingBuses(MessageBusImpl.java:387)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:376)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:364)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.sendMessage(MessageBusImpl.java:355)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$200(MessageBusImpl.java:43)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$2.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:208)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51.modificationCountChanged(Unknown Source)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiModificationTrackerImpl.fireEvent(PsiModificationTrackerImpl.java:93)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiModificationTrackerImpl.incCountersInner(PsiModificationTrackerImpl.java:100)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiModificationTrackerImpl.incCounter(PsiModificationTrackerImpl.java:84)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiModificationTrackerImpl$1.lambda$doIncCounter$0(PsiModificationTrackerImpl.java:68)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1010)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiModificationTrackerImpl$1.doIncCounter(PsiModificationTrackerImpl.java:68)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiModificationTrackerImpl$1.exitDumbMode(PsiModificationTrackerImpl.java:78)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBusConnectionImpl.java:117)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.doPumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:426)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpWaitingBuses(MessageBusImpl.java:387)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:376)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:364)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.sendMessage(MessageBusImpl.java:357)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$200(MessageBusImpl.java:43)
at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$2.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:208)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.exitDumbMode(Unknown Source)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.updateFinished(DumbServiceImpl.java:344)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$pollQueueLater$0(TransactionGuardImpl.java:74)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:447)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:431)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:415)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:763)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: have you tried **rebuilding** project?

Comment: Also File>Invalidate Cache / Restart has resolved this for me in the past if you have not tried yet.

Comment: tried it both, also deleted the auto generated folder manually, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Just tried to invalidate cache again, I got this IDE Error, don't know if related. I'll post it in an update above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem with next lines in `SubmitLayout`

```
binding  = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.submit_list_item);
binding.listItem.setAdapter(adapter);
```

because `submit_list_item` layout don't have `RecyclerView`. You need `activity_submit_layout_`. To fix it you need do next steps:

1. Change type of `binding` variable in `SubmitLayout`

   `private SubmitLayoutActivityBinding binding;`
2. Properly set content in `onCreate()` of `SubmitLayout`

   `@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

   ```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding  = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_submit_layout_);
        ...
   ```

   }

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution, now seeing it seems so obvious.